# What is the best method for L2E Join in following scenario?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Following are two tables:

Country >> CountryId, CountryName
City >> CityId, CityName, CountryId

I am using repository pattern to generate entity set from database. (example, `repository.GetQuery<City>()`)

Now I want to write such a query that when I fetch City it also generates an populates for corresponding Country in the result set. So I can just access it like, city.Country.CountryName.

I know I can perform this by joining two entity sets, but that must be costly in performance. Probably, .Include<> may help me in achieving this. Any idea/ example to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume, since you're using Entity Framework, that your City object has a navigational property of Country which points to the corresponding Country record.

As such, unless you specifically want to use lazy loading, you'll need to use Include. The good news is that you can do the includes inside of your repositories, and not have to write that code on the outside. An example of this can be found [here](http://www.appetere.com/Blogs/SteveM/May-2012/Passing-Include-statements-into-a-Repository).

Let me know if that works.